# xcode-select: error: tool 'actool' requires Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode13

I used XCode 12 in Big Sur 11, downloaded from App Store. But today, Apple doesn't allow me to upload my game through XCode anymore with this message:

```
all ios apps submitted to the app store must be built with the ios 15 sdk Xcode 13
```

So I tried to update XCode to 13, but App Store doesn't allow me because my macOS is not 12.

But I found on the official apple website that XCode 13.2 is available in Big Sur 11.3, so I just updated my macOS to Big Sur 11.6.

https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

But still, I was not allowed to download XCode 13 from App Store and I found apple's official webpage that can download XCode versions manually.

So I downloaded 13.2.1 with something called command-line-interface, uninstall the XCode 12, and install both. I put the XCode.app into the Applications directory.

Launching XCode 13.2 was successful without any error, but the build of my project always failed with this message:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'actool' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

So I searched about it, but nothing related was found. I already tried this:

```sh
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

But nothing changed. Still, I see the same error message. I'm pretty sure that installing XCode by downloading it causes this trouble. But there's no OS update available on my MacBook because Big Sur is my last supported version, and App Store does not allow me to download XCode 13.

How do I solve this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: Go to Xcode preferences -> Locations and check that the Command line tools are properly configured.